# RegEx to match whitespaces in urls

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regexp that allow me to match a dynamic URL in Django 1.5

The URL will be like this: `/file/namefile/` but namefile may contain one or more whitespaces that are converted in `%20`.

For example: URL: `file/fourth test/` is saw as `file/fourth%20test/`.

The `%` character doesn't allow me to use something like this: `^file/(\w)/$` of course.

I need a regex that match that expression whatver the number of spaces (I don't really care about security in this stage of the project) but, being a total beginner, I'm stuck.

Comment: [Literal space character is not allowed in URLs.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/53114) Depending on the encoding, it may either be encoded as `%20` or as `+`. However, browsers may *display* those encoded spaces with an actual space.

Comment: I understood that, that's why I need a regexp that match also the `%20`

Comment: I don't know Django things. But will something like this work? ([\w\%\s\+])

Comment: In your example, the incoming URI is something like `/file/fourth%20test/`? What do you want to do with it, and where (could affect whether you see it as `%20` or as a real space)? Is it in .htaccess or in scripting code such as PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^file/((?:\w|%20)+)/$
```

The `?:` prevents the inner `()` from creating a reference.